# What is the sign of Earth's J₂?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

From Wikipedia's [Geopotential model; The deviations of Earth's gravitational field from that of a homogeneous sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopotential_model#The_deviations_of_Earth%27s_gravitational_field_from_that_of_a_homogeneous_sphere) and the question [For the mathematical relationship between J2 (km^5/s^2) and dimensionless J2 - which one is derived from the other?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22976/12102) I have

$$\tilde{J_n}=-\frac{J_n}{\mu R^n}$$

which has a prominent minus sign. If the dimensionless $\tilde{J_n}$ (roughly 0.001) is positive, then the dimensioned $J_n$ (roughly 1.8E+25 m<sup>5</sup>/s<sup>2</sup>) should be negative.

A quick test in a numerical integrator also shows me that if I don't make it negative then the nodal precession is the wrong direction.

So does the linked Wikipedia article give the sign incorrectly twice? Instead of `+1.7555E+10` km<sup>5</sup>/s<sup>2</sup> should it be `-1.7555E+10`?

---

Quotes from the Wikipedia article

> According to JGM-3 one therefore has that $J_{2} = 0.1082635854 \cdot 10^{-02} \cdot  6378.1363^{2} \ \cdot \ 398600.4415 \ \text{ km5/s2 } = 1.75553 \ \cdot \ 10^{10}$ and $J_{3} = -0.2532435346 \cdot 10^{-05} \cdot \ 6378.1363^{3} \cdot \ 398600.4415 \text{ km6/s2 } = -2.61913 \cdot \ 10^{11} \text{ km6/s2 }$

and

> For JGM-3 the values are:
>
> μ = 398600.440 km3⋅s−2
>
> $J_{2}$ = 1.75553 × 1010 km5⋅s−2
>
> $J_{3}$ = −2.61913 × 1011 km6⋅s−2

---

Quick numerical check using $J_{2}$ = +1.7555E+25  m<sup>5</sup>/s<sup>2</sup>

[image: quick check of sign of direction of precession of ascending nodes using J2 = +1.7555E+25 # m^5/s^2]

$$\omega_p = -\frac{3}{2}\frac{R_E^2}{(a(1-e^2))^2} J_2 \omega \cos i$$

gives a precession of -360 degrees in 89.4 days which matches the numerical check.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint as ODEint
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.optimize import brentq

def deriv(X, t):
    xyz, v = X.reshape(2, -1)
    acc_0 = -GMe * xyz * ((xyz**2).sum())**-1.5
    acc_2 = acc_J2(xyz)
    return np.hstack((v, acc_0+acc_2))

def acc_J2(xyz):
    x, y, z = xyz
    x2, y2, z2 = xyz**2
    r2 = (xyz**2).sum(axis=0)
    r = np.sqrt(r2)
    r7 = r**7
    u = J2 * r**-5 * 0.5 * (3*z2 - r**2)
    ax = J2 * (x/r7) * (6*z2 - 1.5*(x2+y2)) 
    ay = J2 * (y/r7) * (6*z2 - 1.5*(x2+y2)) 
    az = J2 * (z/r7) * (3*z2 - 4.5*(x2+y2))
    return np.stack([ax, ay, az], axis=0)

halfpi, pi, twopi = [f*np.pi for f in (0.5, 1, 2)]
to_degs, to_rads = 180/pi, pi/180

Re = 6378137. # meters
J2 = +1.7555E+25 # m^5/s^2
GMe = 3.986E+14 # m^3/s^2

a = 6378137. + 400000.
v0 = np.sqrt(GMe/a)

times = np.arange(0, 100*24*3600, 60)
inc = 60 * to_rads
sinc, cinc = [f(inc) for f in (np.sin, np.cos)]

X0 = np.array([a, 0, 0, 0, v0*cinc, v0*sinc])

answer, info = ODEint(deriv, X0, times, full_output=True)

x, y, z = answer.T[:3]
crossings = np.where((z[1:] > 0) * (z[:-1] <= 0))[0]
Cux = interp1d(times, x, kind='cubic', assume_sorted=True)
Cuy = interp1d(times, y, kind='cubic', assume_sorted=True)
Cuz = interp1d(times, z, kind='cubic', assume_sorted=True)
times_zc = np.array([brentq(Cuz, times[i-1], times[i+1]) for i in crossings[1:-1]])
zcs = np.array([F(times_zc) for F in (Cux, Cuy, Cuz)])
longinodes = np.arctan2(zcs[1], zcs[0])

if True:
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(times_zc/3600/24, to_degs * longinodes)
    plt.title('400 km orbit at 60 degrees inclination \n assuming J2 = +1.7555E+25 m^5/s^2', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('longitude of ascending node (deg)', fontsize=14)
    plt.xlabel('time (days)', fontsize=14)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: J2 is positive, unitless, and has a value of about $10^{-3}$ (0.0010826359 to be precise). The linked wikipedia page has many errors.